# Help! Attempting to install PowerShell 2 from Windows Management Framework, getting "The update does not apply to your system"

Tags: troubleshooting, installation, powershell

I'm running Vista x64 Home Premium as admin (SP1 not installed)

Steps I've taken:

- Googled the problem.
- Uninstalled PowerShell 1
- Cleaned the local registry via regedit, removed entries containing "PowerShell"
- Rebooted.

I still get the problem. Windows Update Standalone Installer crunches for 30 seconds and then posts the "The update does not apply to your system."

Any additional ideas/suggestions for working around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/968929

**Requirements**

WinRM 2.0 and PowerShell 2.0

WinRM 2.0 and PowerShell 2.0 can be installed on the following supported operating systems:

- Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 1
- Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2
- Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2
- **Windows Vista with Service Pack 2**
- **Windows Vista with Service Pack 1**
- Windows XP with Service Pack 3